# JSON data formation in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to chunk json by it's value using PHP. Here sample json is

```
{
"16506": "10",
"16507": "10",
"16508": "10",
"16509": "10",
"16510": "20",
"16511": "20",
"16512": "20",
"16513": "30"
}
```

my expectation is to format like

```
10=>[16506,16507,16508,16509]
20=>[16510,16511,16512]
30=>[16513]
```

Is there any built-in function is php or have to use loop ? here I used
json_decode() and array_flip(). But array_flip makes it distinct. Thanks in advance

Comment: you're probably looking for that one-liner, someone could probably get creative with one, but yeah just simply loop it and push via key

Comment: A simple `foreach` will suffice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a build-in function called `array_walk`. [Here you can read about it.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

```php
$json = '{"16506": "10","16507": "10","16508": "10","16509": "10","16510": "20","16511": "20","16512": "20","16513": "30"}';

array_walk(json_decode($json), function($value, $key) use (&$result)  {
  $result[$value][] = $key;
});

print_r($result);
```

Result:

```php
Array
(
    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16506
            [1] => 16507
            [2] => 16508
            [3] => 16509
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16510
            [1] => 16511
            [2] => 16512
        )

    [30] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16513
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something below, just need to go through a loop

```
$json = '{
"16506": "10",
"16507": "10",
"16508": "10",
"16509": "10",
"16510": "20",
"16511": "20",
"16512": "20",
"16513": "30"
}';


$ar = json_decode($json);
$newAr = []; 
foreach($ar as $k => $v){
    $newAr[$v][] = $k;
}
print_r($newAr);
```

> Output will be:

```
Array
(
    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16506
            [1] => 16507
            [2] => 16508
            [3] => 16509
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16510
            [1] => 16511
            [2] => 16512
        )

    [30] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16513
        )

)
```

> if you want as string, then implode it

```
foreach($newAr as $k => $v){
    $newAr[$k] = implode(',',$v);
}

print_r($newAr);
```

> Output will be

```
Array
(
    [10] => 16506,16507,16508,16509
    [20] => 16510,16511,16512
    [30] => 16513
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code

```html
<?php
  $json =json_decode('{
  "16506": "10",
  "16507": "10",
  "16508": "10",
  "16509": "10",
  "16510": "20",
  "16511": "20",
  "16512": "20",
  "16513": "30"
  }',true);
$arrys = [];  
  foreach ($json as $k => $sd){ 
        $arrys[$sd][] = $k;   
  }
 
echo "<pre>"; print_r($arrys); die; 
 ?>
```

Comment: Why this? `if(in_array($sd, $json)){`? It will always be true since $sd comes from $json so naturally it has to be true. And your second foreach does nothing at all except moving the data from one array to the other. No difference what so ever. https://3v4l.org/OoeYo